# Why is there no pooler layer in huggingfaces' FlauBERT model?

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

BERT model for Language Model and Sequence classification includes an extra projection layer between the last transformer and the classification layer (it contains a linear layer of size `hidden_dim x hidden_dim`, a dropout layer and a `tanh` activation). This was not described in the paper originally but was clarified [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/43). This intermediate layer is pre-trained together with the rest of the transformers.

In huggingface's `BertModel`, this layer is called `pooler`.

According to [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.05372.pdf#subsection.5.1), FlauBERT model (XLMModel fine-tuned on French corpus) also includes this pooler layer: "The classification head is composed of the following layers, in order: dropout, linear,tanhactivation, dropout, and linear.". However, when loading a FlauBERT model with huggingface (*e.g*, with `FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(...)`, or `FlaubertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(...)`), the model seem to include no such layer.

Hence the question: why is there no pooler layer in huggingfaces' FlauBERT model ?

Comment: Pooler is necessary for the next sentence classification task. This task has been removed from Flaubert training making Pooler an optional layer. HuggingFace commented that "pooler's output is usually not a good summary of the semantic content of the input, you’re often better with averaging or pooling the sequence of hidden-states for the whole input sequence". Thus I belive they decided to remove the layer.

Comment: Thanks, this is consistent with an answer I got from one of the authors, saying they basically started from RoBERTa (which does not include the NSP task).
You can post your comment as an answer since I consider it solves my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pooler is necessary for the next sentence classification task. This task has been removed from Flaubert training making Pooler an optional layer. HuggingFace commented that "pooler's output is usually not a good summary of the semantic content of the input, you’re often better with averaging or pooling the sequence of hidden-states for the whole input sequence". Thus I belive they decided to remove the layer.

Answer (score -1):

Because Flaubert is an XLM model and not a BERT model